# How do I group results by discovered field in Cloudwatch logs query?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I've seen some other examples that are close but I'm unable to group log messages by a discovered field.  We have an error repeated every few minutes until it's fixed but I only need to show one.  My working query is

```
FIELDS @timestamp, external_id, @message 
| FILTER ispresent(external_id)
| SORT @timestamp DESC
```

[image]

But I'd like to only show the latest message per exernal_id.  Anyone know what the correct

```
stats
```

statement is to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
FIELDS @timestamp, external_id, @message 
| FILTER ispresent(external_id)
| stats max(@timestamp) by bin(5m)
| SORT @timestamp DESC
```

The stats max will get the max timestamp as you want the latest and set the interval in **by bin(5m)** as your own requirement. I hope this query will help you out to achieve your goal.